# How to edit Materialize CSS style sheets?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize, css-frameworks

Hi Stackoverflow friends! I've been playing around with Materialize CSS framework and as instructed, downloaded, extracted files and set-up directory structure as per the set-up page. Being all set up, I've now begun to copy certain snippets of HTML from the 'components' section of the Materialize site, which work fine until the point I want to change anything. For example, I thought lets change the colour of the nav bar from the classic Materialize maroon to blue, although I noticed the relative link points to the minified CSS file (which I obviously can't read) - I changed that link to 'materialize.css' (long form CSS), but noticed when I refreshed the page, no styling at all was there? Any tips as to how I can manipulate styling without writing new CSS? If I have completely gone about the wrong way, please let me know also? Many thanks, Nick.

Comment: You can use the minified version, and even better try to use CND version of it (hosted no some fast univarsal servers). And any correction you would like to do to the file just do in your new file.

Comment: CDN version I assume you meant? So I can just create my own style and target whatever specifics I want? Thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: Exactly. This is the way CSS libraries are meant to work

Comment: Thanks brutha - appreciate the help!